# Configuration file for AngularJS app where store the BaseURL for the services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2013, publish, configuration-files

I am working on a project which is published in that way

- A WebApi application hosted on Server1
- An AngularJS application hosted on Server2 which call the APIs on the Server1

On the AngularJS application I have a javascript prototype used for common functions and one of these builds the base url to call the API on server 1 (so, it returns i.e https:\server1\api)

Right now the URL address "server1\api" is hard-coded (I know...i begging you for mercy) on a variable, but what I need is:

1) Use a file for the configuration (I thought should be good to put all the configuration on a single JSon file and load it when the app start)

2) Be able to configure which configuration copy on Server1 during the Visual Studio publishing process of the AngularApp (something like the web.config transform)

The first point is not tough, but how can I create the kind of transformation on the second point and automatically select the right Json file during the publish?

Thank you

Comment: Check out this POST - http://blog.busymachines.com/frontend/angularjs/2013/07/16/managing-api-urls-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Above link doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an angular constant from the angular side, and inject that where needed

```
//define your const
angular.module('MyModule').constant('serverUrl', 'VALUE');
//use your const via DI
angular.module('MyModule').factory('factoryName', function('serverUrl'){});
```

but set that code in your view (assuming Razor

```
angular.module('MyModule').constant('serverUrl', '@(ViewBag.ServerUrl)');
```

and you can pull that data from your web.config, which can be transformed during either your build or release process via a transformation.

It is an odd way to get there but it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you Brocco, but this solution works fine only if the AngularJs is "combined" with MVC. 
But my AngularApp has nothing to do with MVC:  I am not using Razor for the angular app. I have just a bunch of HTML pages.

Comment: Anyway, I have used this kind of approach to let JQuery works with some server side variable in the past, and it works great! :)

Comment: Understood, just took a flyer being that you tagged VS 2013. I'll give it some thought and come back if I get anything else for you.